# Overwrite previous output on same line

Tags: python

I want the output of my code to overwrite the previous output on the same line.

I have read the previous answers to a similar question and have read that I can do this using a ',' and a '\r', but this doesn't seem to work for me. I tried:

```
for i in range(length):
    print 'Minutes:',minute,'of {0}'.format(length),'\r',
    minute+=1
    time.sleep(1)
```

But it doesn't print anything other than the last line of the loop. I've tried other arrangements,but nothing yet has worked. Could someone let me know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: There's no need for special string formatting; you can just do `...minute, 'of', length,...`.

Answer (score 1):

You need sys.stderr for fast output on a screen:

```
import sys,time
length,minute = 10,0
for i in range(length):
    sys.stderr.write('Minutes:{} of {}\r'.format(minute,length))
    minute+=1
    time.sleep(1)
```

Don't forget to add sys.stderr.write('\n') at the end of your loop to avoid printing into the same line.

Answer (score 1):

If You are doing this in Linux, You can simply use ASCII escape sequence to move cursor up one line (`\033[1A`). Of course, You will still use `\r` to move to the beginning of the line. You could use something like this:

```
for i in range(length):
    print('Minutes: ' + minutes + '\033[1A\r')
    minutes += 1
    sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can think of doing this is, if you know how many lines your shell is, then you can just

```
print "\n" * (number_of_lines - 1)
```

then

```
print 'Minutes:',minute,'of {0}'.format(length)
```

So together,

```
for i in range(length):

    print "\n" * (number_of_lines - 1)
    print 'Minutes:',minute,'of {0}'.format(length)
    minute += 1
    time.sleep(1)
```

---

**General Tips**

1. You use commas and `str.format()` in the same print statement, instead just use `str.format()` for all of it. e.g `print 'Minutes: {0}, of {1}'.format(minute, length)`.
2. You used `minute` as your counter even though it appears you are counting by seconds. For clarity you may want to rename that variable `second`.

---

**Note**

`sys.stderr` is the *better* way to do this. Please look at rth's answer

Comment: I do believe this answer is very misleading.  Scrolling the screen by bunch of empty lines, instead of using standard stderr is quite bad solution. What if I want to keep all previous information on the screen? Say for example my code checking some options and some of them require several loops... I want to keep all OKs on the screen and just show that process is going well!

Comment: It's clearly not the *best* solution, however it is *a* different solution.

Comment: @rth Made a note at the end

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Python3`, you can use a code like this:

```
import time

minute, length = 1, 100
for i in range(length):
    print ('Minutes: {0} of {1}\r'.format(minute, length), end = "") 
    minute+=1
    time.sleep(1)
```

However if you are using `Python2`, you can import `print_function` from `__future__` module like this example:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import time

minute, length = 1, 100
for i in range(length):
    print("Minutes: {0} of {1}\r".format(minute, length), end = "")
    minute+=1
    time.sleep(1)
```

**PS:** I have a strange issue when running the last code from my terminal using `Python2.7.10`. The script work but there is not any output.

However within `Python 2.7.10 interpreter` the code works fine.

Test both solutions and leave your feedbacks if you encounter any problems within `Python2`.

**EDIT:**

I think the better solution to avoid the strange issue that i encounter, and i don't know the cause, is using the ASCII escape as @Fejs said in his answer.

Your code will be something like this:

```
import time

minute, length = 1, 100
for i in range(length):
    print "Minutes: {0} of {1} {2}".format(minute, length, '\033[1A\r')
    minute+=1
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try flushing the output before each sleep.

```
minute+=1
sys.stdout.flush()
time.sleep(1)
```